# The notification appears only in the status bar Oreo version

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create a local notification, but I do not understand why the notification is only displayed in the status bar, where is the problem?

Code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel Id";

      NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Ble Fitto Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentText("text");
        notificationManager.notify(34, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `NotificationCompat` for the `Builder` but you are using `NotificationManager` for notifying. Try using `NotificationManagerCompat`, this should solve the issue.

[This link](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#notify) should help you with more understanding if required.